# Open specific tab in other page

Tags: javascript, html, web, backend

I am Newbie. I'm trying to create link to other page with opening specific tab

> For Example i have 2 page (index.html and goto.html)
>   In my index.html there is 3 tab (London, Paris, and Tokyo)
>   if i press go to tab london button in goto page it will send me to page index 
>   and open london tab and if i press go to tab paris button in goto page it will
>   send me to page index and open paris tab etc.

this is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')" id="bb">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" id="cc">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here my goto.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>In this example, we use JavaScript to "click" on the London button, to open the tab on page load.</p>

<div class="tab">
  <a href="index.html#defaultOpen"> <button type="button" name="button">go to tab London</button> </a>
  <a href="index.html#bb"> <button type="button" name="button">go to tab Paris</button> </a>
  <a href="index.html#cc"> <button type="button" name="button">go to tab Tokyo</button> </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Show a tab by default

To open a specific tab on page load, use JavaScript to "click" on the specified tab button:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button> 
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')" id="defaultOpen">Paris</button> 
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" id="defaultOpen">Tokyo</button>
<script>
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Comment: Not a browser new tab. If you see in my index.html. there is 3 tab with content (London, paris, and tokyo)

Comment: Not a browser new tab. If you see in my index.html. there is 3 tab with content (London, paris, and tokyo). And if i open index page in browser, london content default open. I create goto page with 3 button if i click go to paris button i want it redirect to index page with paris content default open

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I think I found your answer:
Show a tab by default
To open a specific tab on page load, use JavaScript to "click" on the specified tab button:

Example
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>

<script>
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: Just change onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" from London to Paris or Tokyo and the tab changes

Answer (score 0):

Just add this part to your code.

```
<a href="index.html#defaultOpen" target="_blank">
```

That should work

Comment: if you look at my code i have use that code but nothing happen. it just open the page normally. if press go to tab paris or tokyo it still open London tab

Comment: This is working but it's scrolling down to the bottom of the page(footer) automatically after load.